# Spring data JDBC cannot create repository Bean - "entity is marked @NonNull but is null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am just beginning to explore spring data JDBC. I have a simple db (postgres) with a questionnaires table that I am trying to query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foster.questionnaires (
    questionnaire_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version varchar(10),
    name text,
    title text,
    description text,
    status questionnaire_status_types
);
```

And Java classes:

(config inspired from [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/17/introducing-spring-data-jdbc))

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.app.foster"})
@EnableJdbcRepositories("com.app.foster.dal.repositories")
public class FosterApplication extends JdbcConfiguration {

    // Config
    @Bean
    NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        //User name and password is fetched from some other data storage

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariConfig.setUsername("postgres"); //TODO: abstract these
        hikariConfig.setPassword("password");

        //The data source created here doesn't have connection timeout value
        //set by me
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<?> loggingListener() {

        return (ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>) event -> {
            if (event instanceof RelationalEvent) {
                System.out.println("Received an event: " + event);
            }
         };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FosterApplication.class, args);
    }

 }
```

(Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="questionnaires")
public class Questionnaire {
  @Id
  Long questionnaire_id;

  String version;

  String name;

  String title;

  String description;

  enum Status { DRAFT, PUBLISHED }
  Status status;

    public Questionnaire(Long questionnaire_id, String version, String name, String title, String description, Status status) {
        this.questionnaire_id = questionnaire_id;
        this.version = version;
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.status = status;
    }

     // Getters and Setters
    public Long getQuestionnaire_id()   {
         return this.questionnaire_id;
    }

    public void setQuestionnaire_id(Long questionnaire_id)  {
         this.questionnaire_id = questionnaire_id;
    }

    public String getVersion()  {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version)  {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTitle()    {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)  {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription()  {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)  {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Status getStatus()   {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status)    {
        this.status = status;
  }

}
```

(Repository):

```
public interface IQuestionnairesRepository<Questionnaire, Long> extends CrudRepository<Questionnaire, Long> {

    @Query("select * from questionnaires where title = :title")
    List<Questionnaire> findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

}
```

However when starting the application, I cannot create the bean for the repository with the following error and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in instantiating this repository:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'questionnairesRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IQuestionnairesRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity is marked @NonNull but is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at com.optum.foster.FosterApplication.main(FosterApplication.java:65) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IQuestionnairesRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity is marked @NonNull but is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity is marked @NonNull but is null
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.<init>(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:33) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:1.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JdbcRepositoryFactory.java:109) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:1.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:1.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be appreciated - spring data jdbc looks promising; however, without the ability to instantiate a repository I am blocked ... :(

Edit: added entity annotation (still same error)

Comment: Are you sure that's an entity?  It's not annotated like an entity would be (with `@Entity` or with any `@Column` fields).

Comment: I believe so - following the hyperlink & spring data jdbc guide I thought Entity was only required if using JPA.. I have tried to annotate with @Entity and the error is still the same

Comment: Spring Data leverages JPA, from what I understand and have experienced...

Comment: @Makoto let me add it to be safe & modify accordingly (see edit)

Comment: @Makoto Spring Data *JDBC* does not leverage *JPA* in any way except maybe for inspiration.

Comment: You shouldn't have type parameters in your repository interface. It should be just: 
`public interface IQuestionnairesRepository extends CrudRepository<Questionnaire, Long> { ...`

Comment: @JensSchauder:  Yeah, I may have been looking at this particular one a bit too quickly.  Or, I have too much Spring Data JPA on the brain.  My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix through some experimentation:

As it turns out I was receiving the error

```
entity is marked @NonNull but is null
```

because the entity I was trying to query had a postgresql enumerated type column, which I represented with an enum in java code (and I guess as a result the entity was not resolving?)... Changing the field to a String column resolved the issue. Perhaps the error messages here could be refined...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose , you have to implement default constructor for your Entity.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9

Comment: I thought I did by implementing the all arg constructor & even with a default constructor the error is still the same...

Comment: Spring Data JDBC does not require a default constructor.